# Letter Arrangement with Permutations

Tags: permutations

In how many different ways can the letters of the word MAMMAL be rearranged so that the letters M are separated?

Comment: "so that the letters M are separated"; that's the tricky part. The numerical answer is 72. I'm just not sure how to get to it...

Comment: Oh, my mistake.

Comment: The number of arrangements of MAMMAL is $6!/3!/2!=60$, ignoring the restriction that no two $M$s be together, so the answer cannot be $72$

Answer (score 0):

You have three $M$s that need to be placed in a line of six without being next to each other. You have a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. Start with three $M$s. Now pick two slots for the $A$s  If they separate both pairs of $M$s, how many choices of places for the $L$?  If one is on an end, how many choices for the $L$.  If they are both on the end, how many choices for the $L$?  If they are together in the middle, how many choices for the $L$?  I think $72$ is badly wrong.